# Do pro-objects in a monoidal category have a completed tensor product?

Tags: category-theory, formal-power-series

Given a monoidal category C it seems natural to define a completed tensor product in its category of pro objects Pro(C) by
$$("lim_{a\in A}" X_a) \hat\otimes ("lim_{b\in B}" X_b)="lim_{(a,b)\in A\times B}" (X_a\otimes X_b)$$
but there seems to be nothing written down in this generality. Is there a catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every class of [weights](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weighted+limit) $\Psi$ (or, more specifically, classes of shape for limits), the $\Psi$-[completion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+completion) of a monoidal category inherits the monoidal structure via (a restricted form of) [Day convolution](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Day+convolution). For instance, this is Proposition 3.2 of Johnson's [Monoidal Morita equivalence](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82455055.pdf) (note that Johnson considers the dual case, of free cocompletions). In your case, take $\Psi$ to be the class of [cofiltered categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cofiltered+category).